# Sending an text to an new intent into a text view

Tags: android, eclipse, android-intent, textview, case

the code goes similary like this :

So i got a button that opens a new intent and there is a code to randomly chose a diferent case .like

case1:
     system.out.println("a");
 break;
case2:
     system.out.println("b");
 break;

so the code choses one , but my problem is i want that text to be sent to a new intent and be displey as a text in a new intent , any ideas ?

Comment: Please be more specific on the issue you encounter, best to provide a minimum (non-)working example.

Comment: New intent being another activity?

Comment: A possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2091465/how-do-i-pass-data-between-activities-in-android

Answer (score 0):

you need to create new intent within each case and pass your text value as string object in `intent.putExtra()` method

```
Intent intent = new Intent(context,youractivity.class);  
intent.putExtra("deal", yourstingobject);
```

Answer (score 0):

What I can get from your question is that you want to send a string to activity and set 
the string to textview in the activity

```
        case 1:
               Intent i=new Intent(this,Other.class);
               i.putExtra("key", "Any String");
               startActivity(i);
```

In Other Class

```
       String value=getIntent().getStringExtra("key");
       now set the string in textview
```

Answer (score 0):

Add your text in an Intent.

```
Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),
   MySecondClass.class);

   intent.putExtra("name", name);
   startActivity(intent);
```

Get value from an intent in **MySecondClass.java**

```
 Intent intent =  getIntent();

 String name    =  intent.getStringExtra("name");
```

Comment: Check this link for example with full source code http://www.javasrilankansupport.com/2012/06/send-data-to-another-activity-simple.html

Answer (score 0):

this is code:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(thisActivity,secondActivity.class);
intent.putExtra("extraText", "number");
startActivity(intent);
```

and in the second activity:

```
Long number=getIntent().getExtras().getLong("extraText");
```

Answer (score 0):

//SenderActivity

```
Intent intent=new Intent(SenderActivity.this,ReceiverActivity.class);
intent.putExtra("yourKey",anystring);
startActivity(intent);
```

//ReceiverActivity:

```
String senderMessage= getIntent().getExtras().getString(("yourKey")).toString();
```